# Attribute is not loaded on Product_List and Layered Navigation

Tags: layered-navigation, collection, attributes, eav

I have a development system, here is everything working as expected. And I have a staging system, here the attribute is not loaded. It feels like, the sytem don't know, that the attribute doesn't exist in the store/attribute_set/...?

I have an attribute `artist_id` and this attribute is not loaded.

The collections are initialized with the attribute:

```
if (!is_null($this->_productCollection)) {
    return $this->_productCollection;
}
$collection = parent::_getProductCollection();
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('artist_id');
```

I checked wether the attribute is in the collection and it is:

```
[_selectAttributes:protected] => Array
    (
        [name] => 71
        [short_description] => 73
        [price] => 75
        [special_price] => 76
        [special_from_date] => 77
        [special_to_date] => 78
        [small_image] => 86
        [thumbnail] => 87
        [news_from_date] => 93
        [news_to_date] => 94
        [status] => 96
        [url_key] => 97
        [required_options] => 110
        [image_label] => 112
        [small_image_label] => 113
        [thumbnail_label] => 114
        [msrp_enabled] => 118
        [msrp_display_actual_price_type] => 119
        [msrp] => 120
        [tax_class_id] => 122
        [price_type] => 124
        [weight_type] => 126
        [price_view] => 127
        [shipment_type] => 128
        [links_purchased_separately] => 129
        [links_exist] => 132
        [artist_id] => 146
    )
```

But when I try to get `$_product->getArtistId()` there is no id.

Debugging on this system is really hard. I tried to find the part where the query is built but didn't find it yet.

*UPDATE*: Flat tables are OFF.

And now the bad part:
A little

```
<?php $_product->load($_product->getId()); ?>
```

in the `foreach` of the `product/list.phtml` fixes the problem ;-)

To be honest: I think I broke something in the database while changing settings directy in the tables.

Is there any connection between attributes and stores?
Any ideas on this problem?

Comment: Doing load on product model will indeed load all attributes, however it is not very efficient especially if you do it for all products in collection.

Comment: REALLY!? :D Thanks ;-) I know this, but it fixes the problem and my customer can see the functionality. At the moment the page needs about 1 minute to load :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have abssolutely NO idea how this happend, here is the end of the story:

The `backend_type` was `varchar` instead of `int`.

It is obvious to me, that the collection can not load the `artist_id` if magento don't know where to look for the value, but why is a `$_product->load()` able to get the value? I have to investigate this.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at attribute settings, make sure that 'Visible on Product View Page on Front-end' is yes and 'Use In Layered Navigation' is yes too (only if attribute is dropdown)

UPDATE:

Another thing you can try is adding:

```
    <product>
        <collection>
            <attributes>
                <artist_id/>
            </attributes>
        </collection>
    </product>
```

In config.xml of a module, in the <frontend> section.

Comment: checked, and is :(

Comment: And flat product attributes index is rebuilt? Check then if the attribute is in the flat tables

Comment: indexe rebuilt all the time, cache is empty (rm -rf) and flat tables are not used.

Answer (score 3):

If it works on dev but not on staging - and the code base is an exact copy - then your issue is your DB itself.

You could very easily confirm by replacing your staging DB with that of your development DB and see if it still happens.

What you are describing just shouldn't happen unless you've been making manual edits in the DB - or the code is different on your two sites.

Comment: "unless you've been making manual edits in the DB" I did. there is the problem. :(

Comment: Then no-one here is really going to be able to answer. If you've been editing the DB directly, you could cause *any* number of problems - all of which are a pig to diagnose. Its not just a case of running the "Magento DB repair" tool. If it doesn't happen on your LIVE site - then just ditch your staging site and refresh it from LIVE. But if its happening on your LIVE site ...

Comment: there is no live site yet, but I imported a lot of products into the stage system. I think, I'll close this question by now to not burn more of all your time. I just thought someone knows the dependencies on a attribute when it is loaded or not. I thought it only need to be in the attribute set, but this is not enough.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a default value for that attribute in the EAV table? Have a look at this query:

```
SELECT
  `t_d`.`entity_id`,
  `t_d`.`attribute_id`,
  `t_d`.`value` AS `default_value`,
  `t_s`.`value` AS `store_value`,
  IF(t_s.value_id IS NULL, t_d.value, t_s.value) AS `value`
FROM `catalog_product_entity_varchar` AS `t_d`
LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_varchar` AS `t_s`
  ON t_s.attribute_id = t_d.attribute_id AND t_s.entity_id = t_d.entity_id AND t_s.store_id = 3
...
```

This is how Magento loads every EAV attribute in collections. As you see, if there is no value set for the default store (no entry in the database, NULL would be fine), the first part of the query will return no result, the LEFT JOIN won't work and your attribute won't get loaded - even if you have a store-specific value.

Unfortunately I ran into this once already, we did something wrong with an import and I had to debug quite a lot until I finally realised what happened. Maybe check your DB.

Comment: no does this help? and if yes, WHY!?! :-)

Comment: Sorry, I edited my answer. I'm still very unexperienced with SE :-)

Comment: I checked my dev system, I have no default value either. It works :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try:

```
$product->getData('artist_id');
```

Comment: as expected empty :(

Comment: Then maybe log the query with `$collection->getSelect()->__toString()` and see what it returns

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the attribute('artist_id') is added to the **Attribute set** to which the particular product belongs.

Comment: it is, the interesting thing is, if I load the product by its ID everything works.